IndentationError: unexpected indent, но все инденты вроде в норме
Возникает ошибка IndentationError: unexpected indent хотя все иденты вроде в норме, я переводил весь код в пробелы и в табы, но все равно ошибка
Код:
if choose == '3':
    os.chdir('bd')
    os.chdir('email')
    email = input('Введи почту:')
    c = 0
    with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            c += line.count(email)
    print(f'Количество совпадений: {c}')
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
            if email in line:
                print(line.strip())

Ошибка:
File "C:\Users\zisho\Desktop\spiydex\main.py", line 91
if email in line:
IndentationError: unexpected indent


Почему  у принта и инпута нет отступов? Так нельзя прерывать блок кода. Закончились отступы - закончился блок

Отступы увеличиваются, если предыдущая строчка заканчивается двоеточие. После input двоеточие не стоит, следовательно...

if choose == '3':
    os.chdir('bd')
    os.chdir('email')
    email = input('Введи почту:')
    c = 0
    with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            c += line.count(email)
    print(f'Количество совпадений: {c}')
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
    if email in line: #лишний отступ
        print(line.strip()) #лишний отступ

После input пробелы не ставятся
